# Trying to calculate price from a checkbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, calculation

So i am trying to create the code to calculate the total price using the checkboxes - Form Code is directly below and then the JS is below that!

I'm only able to use JavaScript to complete this and cannot edit any of the information included in the form.

Thanks in advance & apologies for any formatting issues!

```
<form id="orderForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
<section id="orderToys">
    <h2>Select Toys</h2>
    <?php
    try {
        // include the file with the function for the database connection
        require_once('functions.php');
        // get database connection
        $dbConn = getConnection();
        $sqlToys = 'SELECT toyID, toyName, catDesc, manName, toyPrice FROM NTL_toys t INNER JOIN NTL_category c ON t.catID = c.catID INNER JOIN NTL_manufacturer m ON t.manID = m.manID ORDER BY toyName';

        // execute the query
        $rsToys = $dbConn->query($sqlToys);

        while ($toy = $rsToys->fetchObject()) {
            $toyName = $toy->toyName;
            echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='toyName'>".filter_var($toyName, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)."</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$toy->catDesc}</span>
            <span class='manName'>{$toy->manName}</span>
            <span class='toyPrice'>{$toy->toyPrice}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='toy[]' value='{$toy->toyID}' data-price='{$toy->toyPrice}'></span>
            </div>\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Problem " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
</section>
<section id="collection">
    <h2>Collection method</h2>
    <p>Please select whether you want your chosen toy(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
    <p>
        Home address - &pound;8.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="8.99" checked>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
        Collect from shop - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="shop" data-price="0">
    </p>
</section>
<section id="checkCost">
    <h2>Total cost</h2>
    Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly>
</section>
<section id="placeOrder">
    <h2>Place Order</h2>
    <h3>Your details</h3>
    <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
        Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
        Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id='termsText'>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
        <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" disabled></p>
</section>
```

```
script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    "use strict";

    const l_form = document.getElementById('orderForm'); // get a reference to the form

   
    l_form.addEventListener("click", calculateTotal); 
    l_form.submit.addEventListener("click", checkForm); // check form on submit
    //l_form.termsText.addEventListener("click", checkTerms);
    l_form.submit.disabled = true;


    function calculateTotal() {
        let l_total = 0; // set running total variable to 0

        const l_toys = l_form.querySelectorAll('span.toyPrice'); //get an array of the advert
        const l_toysCount = l_toys.length; // get the length of the array

        // loop through the array of adverts
        for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_toysCount; t_i++) {
            const t_toy = l_toys[t_i]; // get the current advert in the loop
            const t_checkbox = t_toy.querySelectorAll('span.chosen)'; // F6 get the checkbox for the current advert in the loop

            // if a checkbox is clicked, the price (value) for the checkbox is added to the running total variable
            if (t_checkbox.checked) {
                l_total += parseFloat(t_checkbox.dataset.price);
            }
        } //for

        //delivery
        let l_delivery_charge = 0;
        let l_delivery = l_form.querySelectorAll('input[name.deliveryType]');
        const l_deliveryCount = l_delivery.length;

        for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_deliveryCount; t_i++) {
            const t_currentDel = l_delivery[t_i];
            if (t_currentDel.checked) {
                l_delivery_charge = parseFloat(t_currentDel.dataset.value);
            }
        }

        let l_grandTotal = (l_total + l_delivery_charge).toFixed(2);

        l_form.total.value = l_grandTotal.toFixed(2); // F9 display the total


        // validation
        function checkForm(_evt) {
            alert("checking form");
            _evt.preventDefault();
        } //checkForm()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your requirement, you can write it as:

> **l_form.querySelectorAll('span.toyPrice')**
> Here the querySelectorAll should be on the parent div rather than the
> span element.
> Also, **querySelector('span.chosen')** will return the span element and the checked input is found inside that.

```js
function calculateTotal() {
        let l_total = 0; // set running total variable to 0

        const l_toys = l_form.querySelectorAll('div.item'); //get an array of the advert
        const l_toysCount = l_toys.length; // get the length of the array

        // loop through the array of adverts
        for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_toysCount; t_i++) {
            const t_toy = l_toys[t_i]; // get the current advert in the loop
            const t_chosen = t_toy.querySelector('span.chosen'); // F6 get the checkbox for the current advert in the loop
            const t_checkbox = t_chosen.children[0];
            // if a checkbox is clicked, the price (value) for the checkbox is added to the running total variable
            if (t_checkbox.checked) {
                l_total += parseFloat(t_checkbox.dataset.price);
            }
        } //for

        //delivery
        let l_delivery_charge = 0;
        let l_delivery = l_form.querySelectorAll('input[name.deliveryType]');
        const l_deliveryCount = l_delivery.length;

        for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_deliveryCount; t_i++) {
            const t_currentDel = l_delivery[t_i];
            if (t_currentDel.checked) {
                l_delivery_charge = parseFloat(t_currentDel.dataset.value);
            }
        }

        let l_grandTotal = (l_total + l_delivery_charge).toFixed(2);

        l_form.total.value = l_grandTotal.toFixed(2); // F9 display the total


        // validation
        function checkForm(_evt) {
            alert("checking form");
            _evt.preventDefault();
        } //checkForm()
    }
```

Comment: explain some about your solution, illustrate the bug and tell what you are doing for fixing it .

Comment: Thank you so much! can you see any reason that my total still isn't displaying?

Comment: @ShaunaSkelton it should show.